# Shaped pdf page

Tags: pdf, margins, typography

I don't think this is possible but, is the PDF format able to stand shaped pages?

The idea is to produce documents giving a *reading experience* like this one's:

[image]

but to bee seen on a screen. Should I give up and settle with a black mask around the content?

Comment: Weird typo in the pic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell PDF can also have rectangular shaped pages. Everything beyond must be done by cutting the paper after printing it. For a shape like the one in your question this won’t be cheap since the cutting die must be made especially for a single project.

For digital documents: If you deliver a complex shaped page the user will see it on a probably gray background of his PDF viewer, so using a black or gray background can be sufficient. You may consider using a colors background as a design element.

To generate a background you can use a package like [`tikz`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) or [`background`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/background). There are some options, [`shapepar`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shapepar) for instance, to shape a paragraph too. But though it is possible with TeX, I’d use a WYSIWYG software like Scribus or Adobe Indesign.